# Evaluate the complex integral

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

Evaluate the below integral: 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1} \over 1 + x}\,{\rm d}x
$$
How to start ?.

Comment: What are the possible values of $\alpha$ in this problem? 
What are your thoughts on the problem?  Are there any particular contours or methods you were thinking of applying?

Comment: No..  I just want to evaluate the integral

Comment: The question I asked is whether you have any ideas of your own on how to do so.  Also, what are the possible values of $\alpha$?

Comment: We're happy to help you with your homework, but we're not going to do it for you. Beyond just stating the problem, you need to show some of your own effort and thoughts. What have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on? You've presumably been covering various integration techniques in your class, for example; do any of those apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
*We'll assume* $\ds{0\ <\ a\ <1}$ such that the integral converges. Start with the integral $\ds{\int_{\rm C}{z^{a - 1} \over z + 1}\,\dd z}$ where
$\ds{\rm C}$ is a 'key-hole contour' and
$$
z^{a - 1}=\verts{z}^{a - 1}\exp\pars{\ic\,{\rm Arg}\pars{z}\pars{a - 1}}\,,
\ 0 \ <\ \,{\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ 2\pi\,,\ z\ \not=\ 0
$$

> \begin{align}
> 2\pi\ic\expo{\ic\pi\pars{a - 1}}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
> +\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{a - 1}\expo{2\pi\ic\pars{a - 1}} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
> =\pars{1 - \expo{2\pi a\ic}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{a - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x}
={-2\pi\ic\expo{\pi a\ic} \over 1 - \expo{2\pi a\ic}}
=\pi\,{2\ic \over -\expo{-\pi a\ic} + \expo{\pi a\ic}}
=\pi\,{2\ic \over 2\ic\sin\pars{\pi a}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi a}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1} \over 1 + x}\,{\rm d}x=B(\alpha,1-\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi\alpha}
$$

Comment: Note: this assumes that $\Re(\alpha) \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes!